# How to change the layout of a Synergy keyboard on Linux?

Tags: gentoo, xorg, keyboard-layout, synergy

I am using Synergy-plus-1.3.4 on Gentoo Linux kernel 2.6.36-tuxonice-r3.

I am using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CAPS</kbd> to change the keyboard layout on BOTH server and client boxes. It works perfectly if I change the layout using attached keyboard. But, when using the Synergy keyboard (I move the mouse from the server screen to the client and change with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CAPS</kbd>) it has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change your keymapping in X and use synergy, then you have to change it on the server host (the one that you use it from). This only affects what keys are sent by synergy to X on the remote host, it doesn't change the keymapping on that host.

Say you have host A and host B.

- synergyd is running on A
- synergyc is running on B
- If you use xmodmap to change what a key does in X on host A, it will affect what you do if you use Host A's keyboard on host B through synergy
- If you use host B's keyboard, it won't have the changes you made in X on host A.

By the way, you don't have to move the pointer from host A to B using A's mouse in order to use B's keyboard and mouse, you can just use them.